# How to create a SQL Insert Statement from Table Results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am looking for a way to create an SQL statement from a Query Result

Based on the results of my query which contains column names, rowId and Value, I would like to generate a Query which will include the column name and the value to be inserted for that row.

Example:

```
Id | Row_Id | Column_Name   | Value            | Table
50 | 1      | Employee_Name | 'Joel'           | Employee
51 | 1      | Employee_Age  | '54'             | Employee
52 | 1      | Address       | '425 Baker Ave'  | Employee 
53 | 2      | Employee_Name | 'Jaret'          | Employee
54 | 2      | Employee_Age  | '29'             | Employee
55 | 2      | Address       | '423 Loma Rd'    | Employee
56 | 3      | Employee_Name | 'Jolie'          | Employee
57 | 3      | Employee_Age  | '37'             | Employee
58 | 3      | Address       | '896 Baren Blvd' | Employee
59 | 4      | Location      | 'Chicago'        | Office
60 | 4      | Address       | '264 Taler Ave'  | Office
61 | 5      | Location      | 'Detroit'        | Office
62 | 5      | Address       | '296 Forest Ln'  | Office
```

Expected Result

```
INSERT INTO Employee (Employee_Name, Employee_Age, Address) VALUES ('Joel', '54', '425 Baker Ave')
INSERT INTO Employee (Employee_Name, Employee_Age, Address) VALUES ('Jaret', '29', '423 Loma Rd')
INSERT INTO Employee (Employee_Name, Employee_Age, Address) VALUES ('Jolie', '37', '896 Baren Blvd')
INSERT INTO Office (Location, Address) VALUES ('Chicago', '264 Taler Ave')
INSERT INTO Office (Location, Address) VALUES ('Detroit', '296 Forest Ln')
```

Comment: There are a number of tools that will do this for you (e.g. SSMS Boost, RedGate SQL Prompt).  I wonder if you can elaborate on the use case, though - why you can't just insert the results of your select directly into a table?

Comment: In this scenario I am restoring a database and want to keep the original content of the tables, for which I have another stored procedure which will capture all the required data before restore and this is part of the restore stored procedure which will reconstruct the data.

Comment: do you have another table that defines what are the `Column Names` in table like `Employee` or `Office` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with some fun window functions. Here's a sample.

(#x serving as table with your structure, row_id, columnName, columnValue, tableName)

`WITH foo
AS (SELECT Id,
           Row_Id,
           columnName,
           columnValue,
           tableName,
           DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Row_Id, tableName) AS sectionNumber,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Row_Id, tableName ORDER BY Id) AS rowNumberInSection
    FROM #x)`
`SELECT 'INSERT INTO ' + tableName + ' (' + SUBSTRING(columnNames, 0, LEN(FEE.columnNames) - 1) + ' ) ' + ' VALUES ('
           + SUBSTRING(columnValues, 0, LEN(FEE.columnValues) - 1) + ' ) '
    FROM
    (
        SELECT tableName,
               (
                   SELECT columnName + ','
                   FROM foo f2
                   WHERE f2.sectionNumber = foo.sectionNumber
                   ORDER BY f2.rowNumberInSection
                   FOR XML PATH('')
               ) AS columnNames,
               (
                   SELECT columnValue + ','
                   FROM foo f3
                   WHERE f3.sectionNumber = foo.sectionNumber
                   ORDER BY f3.rowNumberInSection
                   FOR XML PATH('')
               ) AS columnValues
        FROM foo
        WHERE foo.rowNumberInSection = 1
    ) FEE;`

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't generate `INSERT` statements.  Simply insert what you want using `INSERT . . . SELECT` with conditional aggregation:

```
INSERT INTO TABLENAME (Employee_Name, Employee_Age, Address) 
    SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN name = 'Employee_Name' THEN value end),
           MAX(CASE WHEN name = 'Employee_Age' THEN value end),
           MAX(CASE WHEN name = 'Address' THEN value end)
    FROM <query> q 
    GROUP BY row_id;
```

Comment: The issue is the result set can contain information for multiple tables, so I cannot use the Columns in the query they have to be built from the results table. My mistake maybe the sample set I included is not complete enough.I will update that.

Answer (score 0):

i like this type of questions :)
here my solution (using Dynamic query)

```
      select *,cast('' as nvarchar(max)) script into #T from YourTable

      declare @Id int,@OldId int =0,@script nvarchar(300),@script2 nvarchar(300)

      update #T
      set @Id = row_Id,
          @script=Case when @Id!=@OldId then 'insert into '+[Table]+' ( '+Column_Name+')' else left(@script,len(@script)-1)+','+Column_Name+')' end,
          @script2=Case when @Id!=@OldId then ' Values('''+[Value]+''')' else left(@script2,len(@script2)-1)+','''+[Value]+''')' end,
          script = @script+@script2,
          @OldId=@Id
      select script from #T t join 
      (select row_Id,max(len(script)) lenScript from #T group by row_Id) X on t.row_Id=x.row_Id and X.lenScript=len(t.script)

      drop table #T
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `ID` column has unique values and `Row_Id` is unique in sense for only one `INSERT INTO` statement it will be same, you can write a query as:

```
select  distinct
         'Insert into ' +[Table] + 
         '(' +
          stuff((
          select ',' + t.[Column_Name]
          from Base t
          where t.Row_Id = t1.Row_Id
          order by t.[id]
          for xml path('')
          ),1,1,'') 
          +') VALUES ('
          +
          stuff((
          select ', ''' + t.[Value] + ''''
          from Base t
          where t.Row_Id = t1.Row_Id
          order by t.[id]
          for xml path('')
          ),1,1,'') 
          + ')'
from Base T1
```

Test code here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/77430/1